# PowerShell - Set Azure Information Protection (AIP) while sending email using outlook & PowerShell

Tags: powershell, email, outlook, azure-information-protection

I am trying to send an email using PowerShell and outlook.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
```

While sending an email AIP box pops up for selecting a label.

Is there a way to set labels programmatically using PowerShell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You need to [add a user property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties.add) in the following format:

```
"MSIP_Label_" & guid_internal_use_only & "_Enabled"
```

But I'd suggest exploring internals of Outlook mail items using [MFCMAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.userproperties.add) or `OutlookSpy` to find out the exact solution. So, try to set assign an AIP label manually then explore internals using these tools.

Answer (score 0):

Two remarks:

1. Regarding answer of Eugene, I was able to find my AIP label guid by inspecting internal headers for a sent E-Mail -> double click -> File -> Properties. However, I have not actually tried replicating the MSIP_Label_guid_Enabled setting.
2. What worked for me was creating a new E-Mail in Outlook, setting the AIP label via Outlook GUI directly, then saving it somewhere as `template_<Label>.msg`.
   Then, you can use `$outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate('<Full_path>/template_<Label>.msg')` and when you send that E-Mail, it will already reuse the set AIP label and *not* prompt as usual.